# glcoud auth login doesn't ask for verification code

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've just installed `gcloud` via `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash` and tried to do

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

It opened my browser and asked for permission, and redirected me to https://cloud.google.com/sdk/auth_success telling me that authentication was successful and I can close the window.

But the expected **"Enter verification code:"** prompt never shows in my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible `gcloud auth login` runs a little http server, and redirects your browser to it and then to the auth_success page, helping you avoid the need to copy and paste the verification code.

You should now find that 'gcloud auth list' shows email address, and that you are fully authorized.

Comment: Could you give me a link to the documentation that you found confusing?

Comment: I was following this doc https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/#auth (I was upgrading from gcutil). I guess my confusion was due to the tool itself didn't automatically terminate even after auth was successful.

Answer (score 0):

By default, gcloud uses a browser redirect to get the authentication code.  If you are on a system without a browser (like an ssh session), you can use the '--no-launch-browser' flag to fallback to the copy and paste method.